# How to set different sizes for individual fonts in CSS?

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-size, katex

I have a wabpage (HTML) that uses different ttf fonts loaded using `@font-face{}` in the cascading stylesheet. But, I find that one of the fonts is smaller than the rest. I have Katex loaded in the same page to render the math.

The problem that I am facing is that, since I do not know how to set a suitable size for each font, when I set a particular font size `a` for elements where I use `font A`, and `b` for elements where I use `font B`, the font also affects the Katex renders of math equations. So if the font A was by default very small, I need to over-ride the default font size and make it much larger to make it look ok, but then the larger font affects the math equations rendered by Katex and makes them extra large!

So my question is:

**How can I set different sizes for different fonts in the `@font-face{}` itself, so that using a particular font doesn't affect the other elements and JS renderers like Katex.**
**I wanted something like:**

```css
@font-face {
font-family:myFamily;
src:url(locationOfTtfFont);
font-size:medium;
}
@font-face {
font-family:myFont2;
src:url(locationOfTtf2);
font-size:larger;
}
```

But, I couldn't get the above to work. Also, looking at the [Font Face Rule @w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp), I found that font-size was not in the list of allowed descriptors. Never the less, in the same W3 Schools article, I found another font-descriptor: `font-stretch`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Font-size should be defined to an element. Using it inside `@font-face` won't take any effect.

Comment: Do you actually want to change the sizes that your fonts a and b render at or is what you want to make sure that the Katex’s font size is consistent and readable regardless of what the surrounding text font size is?

Comment: Either one of them will do @AHaworth. What I want is that all fonts are readable and appear at the same size. But some of my wants by default are very small and others large, so the smaller ones are difficult to read. I want to set there sizes separately, without affecting the size of Katex formulae that are in between the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Katex uses a default font size of 1.2xem where em is the size of the em of the surrounding text's font. i.e. it renders slightly bigger to help make sub and superscripts more readable.

The problem in the question is that therefore the equations' font size changes with the various fonts in use, one of which renders naturally smaller than another so needs to have its size increased - thus making the equations too large.

It is possible to fix the Katex font size, making it independent of the surrounding text's size, by including a font-size setting in the head of the document.
[image]

This may of course cause a different problem, for example if it was required to have much smaller Katex in a footnote so I am not sure it is a full answer to the question. Here's the snippet in case the code is useful for trying different settings out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-AfEj0r4/OFrOo5t7NnNe46zW/tFgW6x/bCJG8FqQCEo3+Aro6EYUG4+cU+KJWu/X" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-g7c+Jr9ZivxKLnZTDUhnkOnsh30B4H0rpLUpJ4jAIKs4fnJI+sEnkvrMWph2EDg4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-mll67QQFJfxn0IYznZYonOWZ644AWYC+Pt2cHqMaRhXVrursRwvLnLaebdGIlYNa" crossorigin="anonymous"
        onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
  <style>
  .katex {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  p {
  margin: 20px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div style="text-align:center;font-size: 20px;">
  The equations' font-size has been set by including:<br><p style="text-align:center">&lt;style&gt;
  .katex {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  &lt;/style&gt;</p> in the head of the document after everything else.
  
    <br>-------------------
  
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">
      This text has font-size: 20px and here is the equation 
      <div id="eqn1" style="text-align: center;"></div>
    </p>
    -------------------
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">
      This text has font-size: 16px but the equation size is the same as above
      <div id="eqn2" style="text-align: center;"></div>
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>

  function start() {
    katex.render("c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}", document.getElementById("eqn1"), {
    throwOnError: false
    });
  
    katex.render("c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}", document.getElementById("eqn2"), {
    throwOnError: false
    });
  }
  window.onload=start;
  </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```